# Generating random number each week in lua (keeping the same number for the whole week)

Tags: php, date, lua, iso8601

I am trying to generate a random multiplier in lua so every new week a new multiplier is chosen.

for example
the first week it could be : 1000 * 1.2
the next week it could be : 1000 * 0.8

and should come from math.random(0.8,1.2)
but I want to keep the random number for the whole week.

I have been able to find a way to do this in php, but when trying to format the date in lua I cant find a way to solve it.

I need the ISO-8601 week-numbering year and the week number.

This php code does exactly this:

```
<?php
mt_srand((int)date('oW')); //this week date('oW') returns 202114
$number = mt_rand(0.8, 1.2); //from the mt_srand above it will always return 1 on this specific week, even if the script is re-executed
$value = 1000 * $number;
echo $value; //current week returns 1000
?>
```

Are there any smart people that can crack this? I find it very interesting concept.
Note: I do not want to store it in database which is the reason of doing it this way.

Comment: In Lua you can get the current day from the beginning of the year `os.date"*t".yday` (today it returns `96`).  I hope you can get the same number in php.  Just divide it by 7.

Answer (score 1):

1. Random number generators in Lua and PHP are different.  So, if you want to generate the same random number on both Lua and PHP, you should not use standard RNG from the library.  You should write such generator manually instead and implement it on Lua and PHP.
   For example, you may implement formula
   `1000000000 % YYYYWW * YYYYWW % 401 + 800`
   to get pseudo-random number in the range from 800 to 1200.
2. This is how you can calculate ISO-8601 week number on Lua 5.3+:

```
function iso_year_week(time)
   -- returns two numbers: iso_year, iso_week (1-53)
   local t = os.date("*t", time or os.time())
   t.day = t.day + (1 - t.wday) % 7 - 3  -- nearest Thursday
   os.time(t)  -- normalize all the fields
   return t.year, math.ceil(t.yday / 7)
end

function get_YYYYWW_number(time)
   return tonumber(string.format("%04d%02d", iso_year_week(time)))
end
```

Answer (score 0):

mt_rand takes an integer as a parameter. If values between 800 and 1200 are required, these can be used directly.

A timestamp is used to test the algorithm for future weeks.

```
$weekInFuture = 0;  //0 this week, 1 next week for test
mt_srand((int)date('Wo',strtotime("$weekInFuture weeks"))); 
$value = mt_rand(800, 1200); 
echo $value;
```

This week I get the value 1140. For the next few weeks 1104, 916 ..

If you don't like the values, you can generate other values if you use 'WoW' for date.